# how to call $.notify in index.js - angular js in mvc application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `custom notify js` from github [link](https://github.com/ashuthinks/bootstrap-notify)

added two files `bootstrap-notify.js` and `bootstrap-notify.min.js`

now in index.cshtml if I use following code directly it is working perfect

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.notify({
        // options
        message: 'Hello World'
    }, {
        // settings
        type: 'danger',delay:1000,timer:1000
    });
</script>
```

but I try to use this in index.js like below it won't wo

```
app.controller('MyConfigController', function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.MyConfigSelected = []; 
   //added same code here
   $.notify({
        // options
        message: 'Hello World'
    }, {
        // settings
        type: 'danger',delay:1000,timer:1000
    });
});
```

> how can call same $.notify() method in index.js which is there in bootstrap-notify.js file , why unable to call directly ?

I tried like following but not working

```
 //MyConfigController.$inject =['notify'];
    //      $.notify({
    //    // options
    //        message: 'Hello World'
    //    }, {
    //        // settings
    //        type: 'danger', delay: 1000, timer: 1000
    //    });
```

`Even not working on button click js function :(`
`getting error : Uncaught TypeError: $.notify is not a function`